# Make One Page Scroll to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using One Page Scroll to create a single page scroll effect as seen [here.](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html)

It worked fine locally, also in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/DS5ZJ/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="embrulho">
    <div class="corpo">
        <section class="page1">
            <div class="page_container">
                 <h1>Benefício1</h1>

                 <h2>Qualquer coisa de especial!</h2>

                <p>Created by Yoooo</p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://www.portal-gestao.com/app/onepage/back-phone.png" alt="phones">
        </section>
        <section class="page2">
            <div class="page_container">
                 <h1>Benefício 2</h1>

                 <h2>eBudget é tudo o que precisas man...</h2>
    <code class="js">
                      $(".corpo").onepage_scroll();
                    </code>

            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="page3">
            <div class="page_container">
                 <h1>É muita bonito não!?</h1>

                 <h2>É mesmo lindo!</h2>

            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".corpo").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        responsiveFallback: 600,
        loop: true
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.embrulho {
    height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.corpo {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.corpo section {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.corpo section .page_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    max-width: 950px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.corpo section.page2 {
    background: #555557 url('../onepage/phones.png') no-repeat center -150px;
}
.corpo section.page2 .page_container {
    margin-top: 240px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.corpo section .page_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto 0;
    max-width: 950px;
    z-index: 3;
}
code {
    margin: 20px 1%;
    float: left;
    width: 48%;
    height: 105px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 5px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
code.html {
    color: #7EC9E6;
}
code.js {
    color: #FFAD00;
}
```

But it isn't working on the server, I guess due to conflicts with the template. See [here.](http://ebudget.portal-gestao.com/)

I tried detecting and cleaning the conflicts as much as possible, but couldn't figured out why is this not working?

Comment: In your fiddle you have a simple set up...But on your site you are pulling tons of scripts from lots of places set things up where you have things pull from /js/,/css/,/images/ (for your sanity).  I checked my console...No errors but lots of messages (I didn't look too deep... just scanned those) but you could have some subtle conflicts possibly script artifacts which makes things really hard.  So do you need all that 'stuff'? If so, you will need to pull things apart and see what it doesn't play nice with your scroll utility or until you see it behaving properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That was my understanding too. The thing is: how to work in Joomla without a template? I still don't know

Comment: I haven't touched Joomla since 2005.  If you need to exclude a file from the template there appears to be a doc on that. http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla (BUT it does say not all plug-ins play nice with excluding).